# how to refresh owl.carousel slider?

Tags: slider, owl-carousel

I have created the owl.carousel slider in Magento 2 and created it in phtml file using the following code.

```
<div class="carousel-wrap">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl("Test_Slider::images/testpage/slider1.JPG")?>"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl("Test_Slider::images/testpage/slider2.jpg")?>"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl("Test_Slider::images/testpage/slider3.jpg")?>"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl("Test_Slider::images/testpage/slider4.jpg")?>"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl("Test_Slider::images/testpage/slider5.jpg")?>"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl("Test_Slider::images/testpage/slider6.jpg")?>"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, create a js file using the following code.

```
 require(['jquery', 'owlcarousel'], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                loop: true,
                items:3,
                margin: 10,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplayHoverPause: true,
                autoplayTimeout:1000,
                responsive: {
                    0: {
                        items: 2.5
                    },
                    600: {
                        items: 2.5
                    },
                    1000: {
                        items: 2.5
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

But this sometimes image is not displayed and its refresh when I scroll the page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/62SOZ.png

So any solution how can I refresh the owl.carousel slider without scrolling the page when it displays a blank image.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the carousel and store it in a variable and using that variable you can refresh the owl carousel. like the below example.

```
var $owlCarousel = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 5,
    loop: false
});

$owlCarousel.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

you can use the same for your case.